# SQL Server Error: Msg 515, Level 16, State 2 - inserting value to ID column? (NOT NULL field turned off)

Tags: sql-server, reference, insert, key

I created some tables, this is one of them:

```
CREATE TABLE JewelryOrders
(
    OrderID INT, 
    JewelID INT,
    Quantity INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID, JewelID),
    FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES Orders(OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (JewelID) REFERENCES Jewels(JewelID)
)
```

and then I tried to insert some data:

```
INSERT INTO JewelryOrders(Quantity)
VALUES ('1'), ('2');
```

However, I got an error message:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 101
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'OrderID', table 'JewelryStore.dbo.JewelryOrders'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The `OrderID` is defined this way in its original table:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    OrderID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID),
    OrderDate DATE NOT NULL,
    SumTotal INT NOT NULL,
)
```

So it is not `NOT NULL` column. Any suggestions?

Comment: `The Orders and Jewels columns are defined this way in their tables: Orders INT IDENTITY` but you are inserting to table **JewelryOrders**

Comment: I edited my post and pasted the original table definition. Sorry, I'm new to SQL.

Comment: You need first insert to table `Orders` and `Jewels` and then to junction table.

Answer (score 0):

That because a primary key column does not allow nulls.

In your code

```
CREATE TABLE JewelryOrders
(
    OrderID INT, 
    JewelID INT,
    Quantity INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(OrderID, JewelID),
    FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES Orders(OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (JewelID) REFERENCES Jewels(JewelID)
)
```

`OrderID` and `JewelID` make up the primary key (composite), which make those two columns not allow nulls, while in your insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO JewelryOrders(Quantity)
VALUES ('1'), ('2');
```

you just specify the `Quantity` column, and that why you get this error.

Conclusion: no column in your `JewelryOrders` table allow `Nulls`.

**[Create Primary Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys?view=sql-server-2017)**

> - A table can contain only one PRIMARY KEY constraint.
> - All columns defined within a PRIMARY KEY constraint must be defined as NOT NULL. If nullability is not specified, all columns
>     participating in a PRIMARY KEY constraint have their nullability set
>     to NOT NULL.

Comment: I have to use both of them as primary keys but foreign keys also. But this OrderID has another value in the Orders table.. So how could I do it then? Doesn't it get the value from that Orders table?

Comment: this comment doesn't say a lot unless it provides an actual solution to the problem